# jQuery doesn't change the size of background image with viewport resizing

Tags: jquery, css

I'm working with a fullscreen element with a background image, but it doesn't work the way I want. I want the fullscreen background image to resize and be centered. What have I done wrong?

EDIT: I want to have an intro div element with a background image that has the same size as the browser viewport. After a lot of searching, I found that I have to use viewport units or javascript for this to work. Here is a link how I want to do it: http://www.genymobile.com/ Sorry if my question is unclear!

**jQuery code**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    fullscreen();

    $(window).resize(function () {
        fullscreen();
    });

    function fullscreen() {
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        $(".fullscreen-container").css({
            "width": windowWidth,
            "height": windowHeight
        });
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
.fullscreen-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: 0% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background: url(images/hav.jpg);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="fullscreen-container">

</div>
```

Comment: Why are you even using JS? 100% is enough

Comment: @Amit Really?! But why are there so many tutorials about fullscreen/viewport with jQuery? I'm using JS because viewport size like vh and vw are not 100% working in all mobile browsers. Are we talking about the same thing?

Comment: Unless your use case isn't clear, then Yes - Really... but if you're unsure, setup a full snippet, and not partial fragments, and ask again.

Comment: Adding `position: absolute` to the container will be sufficient. As far as I see there will be no Jquery needed for your purpose.

Comment: use css see this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31915909/1479535

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for using `jQuery` for this. You need to set the height of html and body to full. Then you can set your element `.fullscreen-container` height 100%.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/k3exf2tb/1/)**

Use **`CSS`**

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not very certain about the use case.

But your problem is occurring is because of wrong CSS use. see the following fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/3rdhf090/

```
.fullscreen-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(http://imagesmtv-a.akamaihd.net/uri/mgid:uma:image:mtv.com:10661039?quality=0.8&format=jpg&width=480&height=270);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you use background shorthand  "background: url(images/hav.jpg)" in last which overrides all above background property in your case properties are "background-position
background-repeat background-size" just use background-image in last or use shorthand background property background: url(http://placehold.it/350x150)  no-repeat center/contain;

Answer (score 0):

The body height of the page will depend on the content. Your container size inherits the 100% of the body. But if there is no content in the body, the height of your container will be zero. If you would like a fullscreen background image which is responsice you don't need JQuery to resize your background-image. You could just add `position: absolute;` to your CSS file.

```
.fullscreen-container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url("https://cdn.photographylife.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Nikon-D810-Image-Sample-6.jpg");
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ABr/eK8X5/7011/